# How to truncating url at the word instead of limit

Tags: path-aliases

**Background info**:
By default, Pathauto has a maximum alias length is 100.

**Request**: It would be nice if this could truncate at the last space before the limit, instead of truncating directly at the limit, so that there are no partial words in the URL.

What is the easiest way to do this Drupal?

Comment: There's no issue for this in the Pathauto queue, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pathauto module uses the core function `truncate_utf8()` to truncate the alias. This call by pathauto uses `$wordsafe=TRUE` in the call to preserve word boundaries.

If you are seeing partial words in the path, this is a core issue for `truncate_utf8`, not a pathauto issue.